# setlocale doesn't work properly in my timezone

Tags: php, timezone, strftime, setlocale

I live in Bangladesh. But when I use this code.
`<?php  setlocale(LC_ALL,"asia/dhaka");
echo strftime("%d %B %Y");  ?>`
Result shows US Timezone. I want to change my timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Locale and time zone are not the same concept.  For example, one can have a US English locale and have their clock set to Japan's local time (perhaps they are traveling).

For PHP, use the [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function to set the time zone - not the `setlocale` function.